# Retrofit simpleXML Converter for nested arrays

Tags: android, xml, retrofit, simple-framework

I am having trouble figuring out how to create a POJO model for simplexml.

Say I have an xml that I want to extract data from that looks like this:

```
<root>
    <station>
        <station>
            <abbr>Abbr1</abbr>
        </station>
    </station>
    <station>
        <station>
            <abbr>Abbr2</abbr>
        </station>
    </station>
    <station>
        <station>
            <abbr>Abbr3</abbr>
        </station>
    </station>
</root>
```

So basically I figured I have an array inside of an Array, So I coded my java model like this:

```
@org.simpleframework.xml.Root(name="root")
public class Root {
    @Element(name="stations")
    public Stations stations;

    @Element(name="station")
    public Station[] station;

    @Element(name="abbr")
    public String abbr;
    public class Stations{
        public Station[] station;
    }

    public class Station{
        public String abbr;
    }
}
```

I tried tweaking the annotations around, but I can't get this to work. I would really appreciate help on this, thank you.

Comment: Your third line says `@Element(name="stations")`, but you don't have a `stations` [plural] element in your XML.  They all say just `station` [singular].

Answer (score 2):

I find the XML structure a bit odd as the child-station tags seem redundant. Nevertheless, if this is what you're going for then these are the annotated POJO's that could work for you (I replaced your 'Root' class with 'MyResponse'):

```
@Root
public class Station {
    @Path("station")
    @Element(name = "abbr") String abbr;
}

@Root
public class MyResponse {
    @ElementList(entry = "station", inline = true)
    ArrayList<Station> stationsList;
}
```

Namely, I've used `@ElementList` to annotate the list of parent 'station' tags instead of plain `@Element` annotations: The simple xml frameworks has both `@ElementList` and `@ElementArray` for those cases, and I prefer the former.

In addition, since it seems the child 'station' tags have no actual usage I've "skipped" over them by using the `@Path` annotation.

If you wish to read more about these techniques, [try looking into the Simple XML documentation on lists](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#list).